# Alternative words for "Decoding"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms, technology, marketing

I'm trying to pitch something about my project. While training on this pitch I got comments telling me that the word "decode" is not appropriate and it's a "blunt" for such type of pitching and for the target audience. We spent time thinking about a better word, but I didn't find any words that would convey the exact meaning in a "smoother" way. The  sentence I used is:

> We will decode X from neural signal

I found words like "fetch", "get the information" but they still somehow odd to me.

Comment: This question can have no right answer. It’s equivalent to asking people for a list of their favorite flavor of ice cream and the asker accepting the post whose flavor seems like it would be tastiest. Such questions are a poor fit for the SE Q&A model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use *extract*. This use is related to the following [definitions](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/extract):

> Obtain (a substance or resource) from something by a special method.
>   *‘lead was extracted from the copper’*
>
> Derive (an idea) from a body of information.
>   *‘there are few attempts to extract generalities about the nature of the disciplines’*

Answer (score 0):

Would any of the following work?

-Decipher

-Decrypt

-Unscramble

-Understand

-Conceive

-Comprehend

-Make out

-Learn

-Know

-Discern

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are going for something a little less technical:

- Unravel
- Untangle
- Work out
- Interpret

Do any of these suit your needs?

Comment: Untangle is an appropriate word I think

Comment: @hbak You may then also like "disentangle"

Answer (score 0):

**unpack**. [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/unpack)

> 4. To elucidate or interpret (the meanings implicit in an utterance or text, for example).
> 5. (tr) to explain (a question, issue, etc) by analysing its component parts